# I want to make dictionary & array from 2d array

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to make dictionary & array from a 2d array.

I wrote codes:

```
data=[[['A','A'],['S','apple'],['W','NY']],[['A','B'],['S','windows'],['W','CF']],[['A','B'],['S','Lenovo'],['W','CH']],[['A','A'],['S','summung'],['W','KL']]]

dct = {}
ans=[]


for i in range(len(data)):
  for j in range(len(data[i])):
    print(j)
    print(data[i][j][0])
    if data[i][j][0] == 'A':
        if data[i][j][0] not in dct:
            dct[data[i][j][0]] = []
        dct[data[i][j][0]].append(data[i][j][2])
        ans.append(data[i][j][1])
    else:
        if data[i][j][0] not in dct:
            dct[data[i][j][0]] = []
        dct[data[i][j][0]].append(data[i][j][2])
        ans.append(data[i][j][1])
```

But when I run the below:

```
dct[data[i][j][0]].append(data[i][j][2])
```

I get `IndexError`:

```
IndexError: list index out of range error
```

My ideal `dct` output is

```
{'A': ['NY', 'KL'], 'B': ['CF', 'CH']}
```

My ideal `ans` output is

```
['apple','summung','windows','Lenovo']
```

I am a python beginner, so I really don't understand what is wrong. How should I fix this?

Comment: explain the rules by which the input list should become `{'A': ['NY', 'KL'], 'B': ['CF', 'CH']}`

Comment: I suggest that you read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on how to debug your own code. One thing that will help is assigning a repeated expression to a variable, for example `current_cell = data[i][j][0]`. Now you can reuse this variable name wherever needed.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest dct  dictionary can be made key has 2d array's 1st array(like ['A','A'] or ['A','B'])'s 2nd element(which means A or B) and value has array of 2d array's 3st array(like ['W','NY'] or ['W','CF'] etc)'s 2nd element.

Comment: You should learn about list comprehensions and dictionary comprehensions. You might be able to do this more easily with these tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is overcomplicated for the task you are looking to perform. Here is one way using `collections.defaultdict` and a list comprehension with `sorted`.

The solution works because `sorted` is stable. So your dictionary by simple iteration and answer by sorting will align.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for i in data:
    d[i[0][1]].append(i[2][1])

ans = [i[1][1] for i in sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[0][1])]
```

**Result**

```
print(d)

defaultdict(list, {'A': ['NY', 'KL'],
                   'B': ['CF', 'CH']})

print(ans)

['apple', 'summung', 'windows', 'Lenovo']
```